i need a solution in plsql query procedure
in this procedure  i need LpPaymentRate table to be joined for include the paymentrate calculation , actually what the paymentrate calculation does is in LpPaymentRate table i have column like id, days , payPercentage , leavepolicyitemId from these our procedure for retro and current month leave will check if any payment rate are present for the current tenant or anything if there is present of payment rate then it will check for days for days it will calculate how many leave is the employee is taken over the policy period if it is of minimum within 15days then it will check to the table LpPaymentRate days column there is data of 15 so it mean days within 15 so currently it matches this record so next it will check the payPercentage it will 100% in the table so there is no lop full pay for that employee , next suppose if the leave taken by employee is more than 15 days like 25 for overall policy period then the first days  = 15 is not matching so there is also another data of 30 in column days in LpPaymentRate table which mean leave within 15 to 30 days so it matches the record then it check for payPercentage there is value of 50% so half lop for the employee then next one is the leave taken from the employee is more than 30 days the above two record were not matching so there is a another condition like 45 days or 50 days or 90 days many the all days were fixed by the admin so it matches the record so it check for payPercentage there is value of 0% which means no pay full lop fo the employee so this is the concept for payment rate, suppose there is no payment rate present for the tanant or id or anything now it will calculate the regualr lop so this is the overall concept please give me the correct and clear query
below is the part where i need my solution

-------------------------- 4. Leaves ----------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
Case 4.a
- Leave applied with retro only
*/---------------------------------------------------------------
-- Get leave history



v_total_lop_retro := 0;
v_loss_of_pay := 0;  -- Reset LOP amount

-- Get leave history for retro
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tt_leave_history;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tt_leave_history AS


SELECT lh.* 
FROM public."LeaveHistory" lh 
INNER JOIN public."Workflow" wf ON wf.id = lh."workflowId" AND wf."status" = 'APPROVED'  
INNER JOIN public."Leave" lm ON lm.id = lh."leaveTypeId"
WHERE 
    lh."tenantId" = _tenant_id
    AND lh."employeeId" = _employee_id
    AND lh."isProcessed" = 'false'
    AND lh."dateFrom" < v_emp_pc_start_date;

RAISE NOTICE 'Checking retro leaves before %', v_emp_pc_start_date;

FOR v_r_leave_history IN SELECT * FROM tt_leave_history
LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Processing retro leave from % to %', 
        v_r_leave_history."dateFrom", 
        v_r_leave_history."dateTo";
    
    -- Calculate retro LOP days
    v_date_temp := v_r_leave_history."dateFrom";
    WHILE v_date_temp <= v_r_leave_history."dateTo" LOOP
        v_total_lop_retro := v_total_lop_retro + 1;
        v_date_temp := v_date_temp + INTERVAL '1 day';
    END LOOP;

    -- Insert PayLeave record
    INSERT INTO public."PayLeave" (
        "id", "tenantId", "dateFrom", "dateTo", 
        "isPaidLeave", "amount", "formulaWorking", 
        "createdAt", "updatedAt", "payrollId", "leavehistoryId"
    )
    VALUES (
        uuid_generate_v4(), _tenant_id, 
        v_r_leave_history."dateFrom", v_r_leave_history."dateTo",
        'false', 
        (v_per_day_salary * (v_r_leave_history."dateTo" - v_r_leave_history."dateFrom" + 1)),
        'Retro LOP calculation: ' || v_per_day_salary || ' per day',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
        v_r_payroll."id", v_r_leave_history."id"
    )
    RETURNING * INTO v_r_pay_leave;

    -- Mark leave as processed
    UPDATE public."LeaveHistory"
    SET "isProcessed" = 'true'
    WHERE "id" = v_r_leave_history."id";
END LOOP;

-- Calculate retro LOP amount
IF v_total_lop_retro > 0 THEN
    v_loss_of_pay := v_loss_of_pay + (v_per_day_salary * v_total_lop_retro);
    RAISE NOTICE 'Retro LOP: % days, Amount: %', v_total_lop_retro, (v_per_day_salary * v_total_lop_retro);
END IF;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
Case 4.b
- Leave applied with current month only
*/---------------------------------------------------------------

/---------------------------------------------------------------
Case 4.b - Current month leave processing
---------------------------------------------------------------/
v_total_lop_this_payroll := 0;
RAISE NOTICE 'Checking current month leaves between % and %', 
    v_emp_pc_start_date, v_emp_pc_end_date;

-- Get current month leaves
SELECT public."fnLeave1"(
    _tenant_id,
    v_cmp_pc_start_date,  
    v_cmp_pc_end_date,    
    v_emp_pc_start_date,  
    v_emp_pc_end_date,  
    'false',              -- isPaidLeave = false for LOP
    _employee_id,
  v_rt_work_schedule                
) INTO v_tt_pay_leave;

IF v_tt_pay_leave IS NOT NULL THEN
    FOREACH v_tr_pay_leave IN ARRAY v_tt_pay_leave
    LOOP
        -- Calculate days between date range
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) INTO v_total_lop_this_payroll
        FROM generate_series(
            v_tr_pay_leave."date_from"::timestamp, 
            v_tr_pay_leave."date_to"::timestamp, 
            '1 day'::interval
        ) AS dates
        WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM dates) NOT IN (0)  -- Exclude Sundays
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            -- Exclude holidays
            SELECT 1 FROM public."Holiday" h
            WHERE h."date" = dates::date
            AND h."tenantId" = _tenant_id
        );

        -- Calculate LOP amount based on working days
        v_loss_of_pay := v_loss_of_pay + (v_per_day_salary * v_to`enter code here`tal_lop_this_payroll)`enter code here`;

        -- Insert PayLeave record
        INSERT INTO public."PayLeave" (
            "id", "tenantId", "dateFrom", "dateTo", 
            "isPaidLeave", "amount", "formulaWorking", 
            "createdAt", "updatedAt", "payrollId", "leavehistoryId"
        )
        VALUES (
            uuid_generate_v4(), _tenant_id, 
            v_tr_pay_leave."date_from", 
            v_tr_pay_leave."date_to",
            'false', 
            (v_per_day_salary * v_total_lop_this_payroll),
            format('Current month LOP: %s days × %s per day', 
                   v_total_lop_this_payroll::text, 
                   v_per_day_salary::text),
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
            v_r_payroll."id", 
            v_tr_pay_leave."leave_history_id"
        )
        RETURNING * INTO v_r_pay_leave;

        -- Update LeaveHistory as processed
        UPDATE public."LeaveHistory"
        SET "isProcessed" = true
        WHERE "id" = v_tr_pay_leave."leave_history_id";

        RAISE NOTICE 'Processed current month leave: % to %, Days: %, Amount: %', 
            v_tr_pay_leave."date_from", 
            v_tr_pay_leave."date_to",
            v_total_lop_this_payroll,
            (v_per_day_salary * v_total_lop_this_payroll);
    END LOOP;
END IF;
-- Final LOP summary
RAISE NOTICE 'Total LOP Summary:';
RAISE NOTICE 'Retro LOP Days: %', v_total_lop_retro;
RAISE NOTICE 'Current Month LOP Days: %', v_total_lop_this_payroll;
RAISE NOTICE 'Total LOP Days: %', (v_total_lop_retro + v_total_lop_this_payroll);
RAISE NOTICE 'Total LOP Amount: %', v_loss_of_pay;




// this is the method i tried but not working 

/*---------------------------------------------------------------
Case 4.a - Leave applied with retro only
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
v_total_lop_retro := 0;
v_loss_of_pay := 0;  -- Reset LOP amount

-- Create temp table for retro leave history
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tt_leave_history;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tt_leave_history AS
SELECT lh.*
FROM public."LeaveHistory" lh
INNER JOIN public."Workflow" wf ON wf.id = lh."workflowId" AND wf."status" = 'APPROVED'
INNER JOIN public."Leave" lm ON lm.id = lh."leaveTypeId"
WHERE 
    lh."tenantId" = _tenant_id
    AND lh."employeeId" = _employee_id
    AND lh."isProcessed" = false
    AND lh."dateFrom" < v_emp_pc_start_date;

RAISE NOTICE 'Checking retro leaves before %', v_emp_pc_start_date;

FOR v_r_leave_history IN SELECT * FROM tt_leave_history LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Processing retro leave from % to %', 
        v_r_leave_history."dateFrom", 
        v_r_leave_history."dateTo";
    
    -- Calculate retro LOP days
    v_date_temp := v_r_leave_history."dateFrom";
    WHILE v_date_temp <= v_r_leave_history."dateTo" LOOP
        v_total_lop_retro := v_total_lop_retro + 1;
        v_date_temp := v_date_temp + INTERVAL '1 day';
    END LOOP;

    -- Calculate payment rate based on leave days
    v_leave_days := v_total_lop_retro;
    SELECT "payPercentage" INTO v_payment_rate
    FROM public."LpPaymentRate"
    WHERE "tenantId" = _tenant_id
    AND "days" >= v_leave_days
    ORDER BY "days" ASC
    LIMIT 1;
RAISE NOTICE 'Payment rate fetched: %', v_payment_rate;

    -- Payment rate scenarios
    IF v_payment_rate IS NULL THEN
 RAISE NOTICE 'Fallback to regular LOP calculation with % days of LOP.', v_total_lop_retro;
        v_loss_of_pay := v_loss_of_pay + (v_per_day_salary * v_total_lop_retro);
        RAISE NOTICE 'No payment rate found. Full LOP calculated: %', v_loss_of_pay;
    ELSE
        v_payment_rate := v_payment_rate / 100;
        IF v_payment_rate < 0 OR v_payment_rate > 1 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid payment rate: %', v_payment_rate;
        END IF;

        IF v_payment_rate = 1.0 THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'Full pay. No deduction.';
        ELSE
            v_loss_of_pay := v_loss_of_pay + (v_per_day_salary * v_total_lop_retro * (1 - v_payment_rate));
            RAISE NOTICE 'Partial LOP calculated: %', v_loss_of_pay;
        END IF;

        -- Insert PayLeave record
        INSERT INTO public."PayLeave" (
            "id", "tenantId", "dateFrom", "dateTo", 
            "isPaidLeave", "amount", "formulaWorking", 
            "createdAt", "updatedAt", "payrollId", "leavehistoryId"
        )
        VALUES (
            uuid_generate_v4(), _tenant_id, 
            v_r_leave_history."dateFrom", v_r_leave_history."dateTo",
            false, 
            (v_per_day_salary * v_total_lop_retro * (1 - v_payment_rate)),
            'Retro LOP calculation', 
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
            v_r_payroll."id", v_r_leave_history."id"
        );
    END IF;

    -- Mark leave as processed
    UPDATE public."LeaveHistory"
    SET "isProcessed" = true
    WHERE "id" = v_r_leave_history."id";
END LOOP;

-- Summary notice
IF v_total_lop_retro > 0 THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Retro LOP: % days, Amount: %', v_total_lop_retro, v_loss_of_pay;
END IF;

/---------------------------------------------------------------
Case 4.b - Current month leave processing
---------------------------------------------------------------/
v_total_lop_this_payroll := 0;
v_loss_of_pay := 0;  -- Reset LOP amount

RAISE NOTICE 'Checking current month leaves between % and %', 
    v_emp_pc_start_date, v_emp_pc_end_date;

-- Get current month leaves
SELECT public."fnLeave1"(
    _tenant_id,
    v_cmp_pc_start_date,  
    v_cmp_pc_end_date,    
    v_emp_pc_start_date,  
    v_emp_pc_end_date,  
    false,  -- isPaidLeave = false for LOP
    _employee_id,
    v_rt_work_schedule                
) INTO v_tt_pay_leave;

IF v_tt_pay_leave IS NOT NULL THEN
    FOREACH v_tr_pay_leave IN ARRAY v_tt_pay_leave LOOP
        -- Calculate LOP days
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_total_lop_this_payroll
        FROM generate_series(
            v_tr_pay_leave."date_from"::timestamp, 
            v_tr_pay_leave."date_to"::timestamp, 
            '1 day'::interval
        ) AS dates
        WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM dates) NOT IN (0)  -- Exclude Sundays
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM public."Holiday" h
            WHERE h."date" = dates::date
            AND h."tenantId" = _tenant_id
        );

        -- Calculate payment rate
        v_leave_days := v_total_lop_this_payroll;
        SELECT "payPercentage" INTO v_payment_rate
        FROM public."LpPaymentRate"
        WHERE "tenantId" = _tenant_id
        AND "days" >= v_leave_days
        ORDER BY "days" ASC
        LIMIT 1;
RAISE NOTICE 'Payment rate fetched: %', v_payment_rate;

        -- Payment rate scenarios
        IF v_payment_rate IS NULL THEN
 RAISE NOTICE 'Fallback to regular LOP calculation with % days of LOP.', v_total_lop_this_payrollo;
            v_loss_of_pay := v_loss_of_pay + (v_per_day_salary * v_total_lop_this_payroll);
        ELSE
            v_payment_rate := v_payment_rate / 100;
            v_loss_of_pay := v_loss_of_pay + (v_per_day_salary * v_total_lop_this_payroll * (1 - v_payment_rate));

            -- Insert PayLeave record
            INSERT INTO public."PayLeave" (
                "id", "tenantId", "dateFrom", "dateTo", 
                "isPaidLeave", "amount", "formulaWorking", 
                "createdAt", "updatedAt", "payrollId", "leavehistoryId"
            )
            VALUES (
                uuid_generate_v4(), _tenant_id, 
                v_tr_pay_leave."date_from", v_tr_pay_leave."date_to",
                false, 
                (v_per_day_salary * v_total_lop_this_payroll * (1 - v_payment_rate)),
                'Current month LOP calculation', 
                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                v_r_payroll."id", v_tr_pay_leave."leave_history_id"
            );
        END IF;

        -- Mark leave as processed
        UPDATE public."LeaveHistory"
        SET "isProcessed" = true
        WHERE "id" = v_tr_pay_leave."leave_history_id";

        RAISE NOTICE 'Processed leave: % to %, Days: %, Amount: %', 
            v_tr_pay_leave."date_from", v_tr_pay_leave."date_to",
            v_total_lop_this_payroll,
            v_loss_of_pay;
    END LOOP;
END IF;


The code sample doesn't look like Oracle PL/SQL. Aside from all the detailed business logic, what is the technical issue you are having? How is it related to PL/SQL Developer?
